# Error "Could not load file or assembly xxx"

Tags: c#, .net, shared-libraries

I have a problem when referencing to libraries. I give an example to understand:

> - Library A references to library X version 1.0
> - Library B references to library X version 1.1
> - Library X have few small changes from version 1.0 to 1.1

My project import library A, B and X (version 1.0). Everything compiles successfully but in run time, I get a error "Could not load file or assembly X version 1.1" from library B.

How to solve this problem and force my application not to need to check version in this case.
Thanks.

Comment: Search for "publisher redirect policy". Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16946613/project-reference-properties-version-number/16947214#16947214

Comment: These libraries are 3rd libraries. I must get source codes to rebuild B with X version 1.0?

Comment: I read your question as "how to load 1.1 version of assembly X even if one of the other assemblies wants 1.0 version of X". Answer is to use "publisher redirect policy" to load "X1.1" when any  assembly  needs X1.0 or X1.1. But rereading the question you probably have some other problem (like not installing X in GAC and as result not able to store 2 versions in the same folder)...

Comment: I applied "publisher redirect policy" but this error still occurs. I don't use any GAC in my projects.

Comment: I bet you simply don't have X1.1 next to executable (but have X1.0 instead) since you can't have 2 files with the same name...

Comment: Yes, only one X and its version is 1.0. As in my question, my project imports library A, B and X1.0

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31747/discussion-between-lu-lu-and-alexei-levenkov)